# RegEx - Order of OR'd values in capture group changes results

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, xpath

Visual Studio / XPath / RegEx:

Given Expression:

```
(?<TheObject>(Car|Car Blue)) +(?<OldState>.+) +---> +(?<NewState>.+)
```

Given Searched String:

```
Car Blue Flying ---> Crashed
```

I expected:

```
TheObject = "Car Blue"
OldState = "Flying"
NewState = "Crashed"
```

What I get:

```
TheObject = "Car"
OldState = "Blue Flying"
NewState = "Crashed"
```

Given new RegEx:

```
(?<TheObject>(Car Blue|Car)) +(?<OldState>.+) +---> +(?<NewState>.+)
```

Result is (what I want):

```
TheObject = "Car Blue"
OldState = "Flying"
NewState = "Crashed"
```

I conceptually get what's happening under the hood; the RegEx is putting the first (left-to-right) match it finds in the OR'd list into the `<TheObject>` group and then goes on.

The OR'd list is built at run time and cannot guarantee the order that "Car" or "Car Blue" is added to the OR'd list in `<TheObject>` group. (This is dramatically simplified OR'd list)

I could brute force it, by sorting the OR'd list from longest to shortest, but, I was looking for something a little more elegant.

Is there a way to make `<TheObject>` group capture the largest it can find in the OR'd list instead of the first it finds?  (Without me having to worry about the order)

Thank you,

Comment: Really interesting question. I don't think you have an option other than ordering by length (Reverse-alphabetically may be faster/easier?) Or perhaps delimiting/marking the string like `<Car Blue> Flying ---> Crashed` or rather `<Noun> <Action> ----> <Result>` But yes, your regex is basically saying "anything that matches the immediate need, space, and then anything after. The only way it would make a longer choice is if it needs `Cars` or `Carpool` instead. Or if you can place some restraints on whatever flying is a placeholder for, like it can't contain spaces, but that leads to backtracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally automatically agree with an answer like ltux's, but not in this case.

You say the alternation group is generated dynamically. How frequently is it generated dynamically? If it's every user request, it's probably faster to do a quick sort (either by longest length first, or reverse-alphabetically) on the object the expression is built from than to write something that turns `(Car|Car Red|Car Blue)` into `(Car( Red| Blue)?)`.

The regex may take a bit longer (you probably won't even notice a difference in the speed of the regex) but the assembly operation may be much faster (depending on the architecture of the source of your data for the alternation list).

In simple test of an alternation with 702 options, in three methods, results are comparable using an option set like this, but none of these results are taking into calculation the amount of time to build the string, which grows as the complexity of the string grows.

The options are all the same, just in different formats

- zap

  - zap
  - yes
  - xerox
  - ...
  - apple
- yes

  - zap
  - yes
  - xerox
  - ...
  - apple
- xerox

  - zap
  - yes
  - xerox
  - ...
  - apple
- ...
- apple

  - zap
  - yes
  - xerox
  - ...
  - apple

Using Google Chrome and Javascript, I tried <strike>three</strike> (edit: four) different formats and saw consistent results for all between 0-2ms.

- '[Optimized factoring](https://regex101.com/r/zRS3Af/2)' `a(?:4|3|2|1)?`
- [Reverse alphabetically sorting](https://regex101.com/r/eSjIpu/2) `(?:a4|a3|a2|a1|a)`
- [Factoring](https://regex101.com/r/G5Hls4/3) `a(?:4)?|a(?:3)?|a(?:2)?|a(?:1)?`. All are consistently coming in at 0 to 2ms (the difference being what else my machine might be doing at the moment, I suppose).
- **Update:** I found a way that you may be able to do this without sorting in Regular Expressions, using a lookahead [like this](https://regex101.com/r/w9NLBA/1) `(?=a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5)(.{15}|.(14}|.{13}|...|.{2}|.)` where 15 is the upper bound counting all the way down to the lower bound.

  - Without some restraints on this method, I feel like it can lead to a lot of problems and false positives. It would be my least preferred result. If the lookahead matches, the capture group `(.{15}|...)` *will* capture more than you'll desire on any occasion where it can. In other words, it will reach ahead past the match.

Though I made up the term Optimized Factoring in comparison to my Factoring example, I can't recommend my Factoring example syntax for any reason. Sorted would be the most logical, coupled with easier to read/maintain than exploiting a lookahead.

You haven't given much insight into your data but you may still need to sort the sub groups or factor further if the sub-options can contain spaces and may overlap, further diminishing the value of "Optimized Factoring".

**Edit:** To be clear, I am providing a thorough examination as to why no form of factoring is a gain here. At least not in any way that I can see. A simple `Array.Sort().Reverse().Join("|")` gives exactly what anyone in this situation would need.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, explanation, and especially the example links to regex101.  As clever as those solutions are, it seems to me that they're more complicated than just sorting by length the OR'd list as I build it, putting the longest at the beginning of the list.  Ensuring that subsets (e.g. "Car") always follows super-sets (e.g. "Car Blue").  Thanks

Comment: @HexaGamnon Hey, no problem. Though I still can't understand how sorting values by length is easier than sorting reverse alphabetically VB Example: `Dim arr As String() = {"car", "1", "Car blue", "car red", "a", "car cyan", "Car Orange", "b"}` `Array.Sort(arr)` `Array.Reverse(arr)` `Debug.Print(String.Join("|", arr))` gives you `car red|Car Orange|car cyan|Car blue|car|b|a|1` with any fullstop matches (like 'car') being further than anything they might prevent proper matching to, like `Car Blue`. Anyway, have a nice night.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Love your vb code. Didn't think about using `Array` like that; I'm sure that C++/CLI has a similar mechanism.  By 'too complicated', I meant that your nested solutions were more complicated than sorting the OR'd list. Anyway, I was hoping for a clever little RegEx switch that would fix my problem, but, you and @ltux are right, the only way to do it was change the structure of the OR'd list of object names. Thank You!

Comment: @HexaGamnon Oh I absolutely don't support nested solutions in this case. I was simply providing a thorough defense for why the effort of a nested solution provided no measurable benefit. Readability, which can be a factor, isn't a concern here since noone will be manually editing the portion of the regex. With my 702 options, I was only showing that regex can handle large lists (if you have a large list) with ease.

Comment: Definitely agree. The OP was dramatically simplified. The actual RegEx is 1,600 characters long and hundreds of them pale in comparison to a single file write.  :-0  Readability, Simplicity, & Elegant code is a big thing for me. **Thank You** for all your effort at working on this.

Answer (score 2):

The `|` operator of regular expression usually uses Aho–Corasick algorithm under the hood. It will always stop at the left most match it found. We can't change the behaviour of `|` operator.
So the solution is to avoid using `|` operator. Instead of `(Car Blue|Car)` or `(Car|Car Blue)`, use `(Car( Blue)?)`.

```
(?<TheObject>(Car( Blue)?) +(?<OldState>.+) +---> +(?<NewState>.+)
```

Then the `<TheObject>` group will always be `Car Blue` in the presence of `Blue`.

Comment: I suspect that you and @cfqueryparam are right.  The only way to do it was change the order or structure of the OR'd list. Definitely helpful.  Thank You!